# How to prevent iFrame video play without authentication

Tags: php, html, angularjs, iframe

I would like to give access to videos, only if there is a valid subscription. I have achieved this as follows:

**The codes**

```
<div ng-show="(ax.indexOf('V') >= 0">                                                                                                   
<iframe ng-src="someurl/{{video_id}}" type="text/html" ></iframe>
</div>
```

With `(ax.indexOf('V') >= 0` given by:

```
<?php

...
    $ax = (strtotime($row_user['expiration']) > time() ? 'V' : '');        

?>
```

Whereby `expiration` and `video_id` are table columns with resp. the dates of expiration for each user, and unique `video_id`s generated by the provider.

The iFrame is from an external video hosting provider, which hosts all videos and allows domain-specific embedding, thus videos can only be watched on my website. Each video has its own unique `video_id`.

**The possible issue**

I show the videos only to users who have a valid account, and it works, however, I'm not sure if the method `ng-show` is secure. This only prevents showing the iframe but presumably does not block the video from playing if there is a trick to do so. I'm not sure if the `video_id`, once known or tracked by a user, can be used to play the videos (after the account has expired).

I was thinking of hashing the `video_id`s, to prevent tracking from inspecting elements or the source code, but I'm not sure if this is the right logic.

Is there a smart and efficient solution, if not a solution at all?

I'm not a pro coder, but I can implement codes if the explanation is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this is unreliable.. having the `iframe` within the HTML code would expose it to anyone who is able to get to the page. If this is all served in frontend, then there would be no point for me to auth to see the iframe contents..

You should first do the auth, then stream parts of the videos with short expiration via your servers, not offloading via iframe (if of course yo want it to be secure)

I would assume you have not read articles on how for example youtube streams video? or Vimeo? or any other big video provider..

The concept is clear, but it would take a lot of resources to do it right.